# Firemonkey - TPopUp memory issue

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am facing a strange issue. I have set of buttons in a panel and I want to show tooltip for each button. For that I am using TPopUp, but whenever mouse enter, I can observe that memory is increasing for the application. But if I comment the mouse enter and mouse leave events then memory doesn't increase. Did I miss something?

Whenever the mouse enters the button, I can see 0.3MB increase in my task manager.

```
TfrmEncode = class(TForm)    
    pnlTop: TPanel;
    btnSaveToJSON: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSaveToJSONMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSaveToJSONMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    pop : TPopup;
    cb : TColorBox;
    labelText: TLabel;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TfrmEncode.btnSaveToJSONMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Pop.IsOpen := True;
end;

procedure TfrmEncode.btnSaveToJSONMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Pop.IsOpen := False;
end;

procedure TfrmEncode.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    pop := TPopup.Create(self);
    pop.Parent:= self;
    pop.Width:=200;

    cb := TColorBox.Create(pop);
    cb.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
    cb.Color := TAlphaColors.White;
    pop.AddObject(cb);

    labelText := TLabel.Create(pop);
    labelText.Align  :=TAlignLayout.alClient;
    labelText.Parent := pop;
    labelText.Text := 'This is the hint This is the hint This is the hint This is the hint This is the hint This is the hint This is the hint This is the hint This is the hint This is the hint';
    pop.AddObject(labelText);

    pop.PlacementTarget := btnSaveToJSON;
    pop.Placement:=TPlacement.BottomCenter;
  finally
  end;

end;

procedure TfrmEncode.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(pop);
end;
```

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I created the popup only once

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in `TPopup` control. Reported as [RSP-21438](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21438)

`TPopup` internally creates new `TCustomPopupForm` every time popup is open. However, that form does not get released when popup is closed (as it should) but only when popup control itself is destroyed.

There are few workarounds

**1. Create new TPopup control on open and free it on close**

**2. Fix `FMX.Controls` and `FMX.Forms`**

Error can be fixed in implementation section of the above units. That means you can copy `FMX.Controls` and `FMX.Forms` into your project folder and Delphi will use those fixed units instead of default ones.

Fix following code:

*FMX.Controls* - change constructor parameter from `False` to `True` - it means popup form will be automatically released on close.

```
function TPopup.CreatePopupForm: TFmxObject;
...
    NewForm := TCustomPopupForm.Create(Self, NewStyle, PlacementTarget, True);
```

*FMX.Forms* - assign `AutoFree` parameter to field.

```
constructor TCustomPopupForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent; AStyleBook: TStyleBook = nil; APlacementTarget: TControl = nil;
  AutoFree: Boolean = True);
var
  NewStyleBook: TStyleBook;
begin
  FAutoFree := AutoFree;
....
```

Comment: Thanks. I used both workarounds but still the issue persists.

Comment: It should not, I tested it. Maybe there is something else you didn't show in your code here. But you have to enter and leave button more than once to see that memory is not constantly increasing. Creating form even once will result with small memory increase. If you are not sure, put the breakpoint in TCustomPopupForm.Destroy to confirm it is called.

Comment: Ok I will check and post the results here